# Expandable scroll view not scrolling

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, expandablelistview

I want to make a layout in which pie chart also scrolls along with expandable list view just like an analysis and reports screen however with this layout only 1st item of expandable list view is visible and not able to scroll expandable list view tried:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

but this only enables scolling for expandable list view and not pie chart (it should as i want to make it appear as a normal screen)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DashboardFragment">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/scheduleSpinner"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/scheduleSpinner">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/pieChart_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListOverview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Modify relative layout to just have the spinner and ExpandableListView, then in program  code, create/inflate PieChart and add it as header view to the ExpandableListView.